# Math operation in JS

Tags: javascript, math, operation

my code is suppose to calculate mortgage payments

```
var LA = 100000;
var RA=0.07;
var YA=30;

var R = ( RA / 12);
var r = (1 + R);
var Yr = (YA * 12);
var pay = (LA * Math.exp(r,Yr)*R)/(Math.pow(r,Yr)-1);
```

returns $224.12

which is wrong it needs to be $665.30
payment = [ LA * r^Yr * R ] / [ r ^Yr - 1]

For example:

30 year mortgage for $100,000 at 7% interest (0.07)

0.07 / 12 = 0.00583 (this is R)

30 * 12 = 360 (this is Yr)

1 + 0.00583 = 1.00583 (this is r)

payment = [ $100,000 * (1.00583)^360 * 0.00583 ] / [ (1.00583)^360 - 1 ]

Monthly Payments will be $665.30

any tips?

Comment: You cannot use square brackets in algebraic expressions.  Just parentheses (round ones).

Comment: (LA * Math.exp(r,Yr)*R)/(Math.pow(r,Yr)-1); returns the same  so i dont believe that is the issue but rather an standard that needs to be implemented

Comment: It is absolutely, positively true that square brackets should not be used as parts of algebraic computational expressions. They're syntactically valid because they construct **arrays** in JavaScript, and due to the way automatic type coercion happens you don't get errors, but they will absolutely not do what you think they do and you're asking for trouble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the correct function: `Math.pow` and not `Math.exp`.

Also, although square brackets will work, it's only because JavaScript is casting the arrays to strings, and then to numbers. Use parentheses instead.

Comment: Is `Math.exp` silently ignoring the second argument?

Comment: Pretty much, yes. It's not an error to have too many arguments - nor is it one to have too few (although that ususally causes other errors)